# Вызов события для обработки исключения

Tags: c#, .net, исключения, события, архитектура

Введение

Ведеться разработка приложения на C# , с использованием паттерна MVP. 
Есть Модель, к которой обращаються через интерфейс, возможно добавление адаптера.

Суть вопроса.

Практично ли получать сообщение и параметры исключения через События из Модели, т.е. Событие создаеться внутри модели, а обработчик извне и желательно узнать какие есть еще удачные решения для решения данной проблемы.

Примера нет т.к.идет разработка "на бумаге"

Схема взаимодействия.

Presenter

```
... 
    ISomeModel model = new SomeModel() ;
    model.erroraction += Errorhandler;
...
    model.SomeFunc();
...
void Errorhandler(//какието параметры//) {
    //сохранение параметров в памяти
    //и отображение во  view
}
```

SomeModel

```
...
void SomeFunc() {
... 
event Action<//типы//> erroraction;
... 
    try{
        //some work
    } catch (Exception) {
        erroracion.Invoke(//параметры//);
    }
... 
} 
...
```

Модель не знает о представителе.

Comment: `Практично ли получать сообщение и параметры исключения через События из Модели` зачем?

Comment: Чтобы в дальнейшем их отобразить в представлении.

Comment: Зачем исключения показывать в представлении через события?

Comment: я имею ввиду, почему `try{...}catch(Exception e){... показать эксепшон ...}` не работает для вас?

Comment: Модель не знает кто ее вызвал, представитель должен запомнить информацию об исключении, чтобы затем можно было посмотреть ошибки текущего сеанса.

Comment: И по требованию пользователя представитель заставит представление отобразить журнал ошибок.

Comment: мне кажется, не хватает какого то примера кода, а то я, например, не очень понял вашу архитектуру и как имено вы хотите показывать исключения. Также было бы неплохо добавить теги, что у вас за технология - WPF/Winforms, и почему вам не подходит, например, перехват исключения на уровне приложения / логгера, запись его куда то в память, и потом показа исключений уже просто из памяти логгера

Comment: @tym32167Спасибо, как-то не подумал про чтение из логгера

Comment: @tym32167 А событие вызывать, чтобы представитель обновил представление? Чтобы при особых исключениях ошибка сразу появлялась.

Comment: Ну вы же используете логгирование? Я бы накатал свою версию логгера (чтобы он работал (вместе, но не вместо) с обычным логгером в файл), в этом логгере есть метод типа `LogError(Exception ex)`,  а раз мой кастомный логгер  может принимать эксепшоны, пусть хранит их в чем то типа `ObservableCollection`, ну или логгеру пропишите event если вам прямо события нужны.